# How to Handle NullpointerException when Query throws Exception?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-jdbc

I am having one query.That query is having an input,If the input found in Database then it will return sum value. If the input is not found in db then it will throw exception.

```
String Query="SELECT SUM(tot) FROM Test where Id=?";

double sum = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
        Query, new Object[] { Id }, Double.class);

return sum;
```

If the Id present In db then It will return sum value.Otherwise It will return NullPointerException.I want to Handle that exception.If I got NullPointer then I want to set Sum value as 0.

Comment: Catch the exception.

Comment: directly null pointer?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `java.lang.Double` instead of a primitive `double`, and then programatically check for `null`:

```
String Query="SELECT SUM(tot) FROM Test where Id=?";

Double sum = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
             Query, new Object[] { Id }, Double.class);

return Optional.ofNullable(sum).orElse(0.0);
```